# How to insert a variable in a regex pattern?

Tags: python, regex

i  have a list :

```
cpt=0
list=["dermato","bioderma", "gatoderma"]
for l in list:
 if re.findall(".*derma.*",l):
     cpt=cpt+1
```

So, instead of putting directly  'derma' as regex , i want :

```
a= "derma"   #initialize
list=["dermato","bioderma", "gatoderma"]
for l in list:
if re.findall(".*a.*",l):
     cpt=cpt+1
```

Comment: Use string concatenation, `str.format`, f-strings, etc.

Comment: The regex still has to be compiled, doesn't matter where you put the string. You would like to save time, but it doesn't matter how it's done takes the same time.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can use an f-string:

```
a=  "derma"
list = ["dermato","bioderma", "gatoderma"]
for l in list:
if re.findall(f".*{a}.*", l):
     cpt += 1
```